# Notation of natural isomorphisms using dash

Tags: category-theory, notation

What does this notation of a natural isomorphism [used in the context of adjunctions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_functors#Monads) mean:

$$Φ : \hom_C(F-,–) → \hom_D(–,G–)$$

My assumption would be that $\hom_C(F-,–)$ means collection of hom-sets $FX \to X, \forall X \in C$ and second one accordingly. Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two dashes do not necessarily represent the same object, in the first place because the categories $\mathcal C$ and $\mathcal D$ are not necessarily the  same.

Actually, for any objects  $X$ in $\mathcal D$, $Y$ in $\mathcal C$, you have a bijection
$$\Phi_{X,Y}\colon\operatorname{Hom}_{\,\mathcal C}\bigl(F(X),Y\bigr)\longrightarrow\operatorname{Hom}_{\mkern2mu\mathcal D}\bigl(X,G(Y)\bigr)$$

Comment: What is the advantage of using the dashes as opposed to variables? It seems to me quite arbitrary to introduce this new kind of notation, which is analogous to an already established notation.

Comment: It's not really new. It means your imagination has to fill the form. Other people use `*` or a bullet.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, these are actually bifunctors $D^{op}\times C\to \mathbf{Set}$; this means that they depend on two variables $X\in D$, $Y\in C$ (contravariantly on $X$ and covariantly on $Y$), with each dash representing one variable. So $\operatorname{hom}_C(F\_,\_)(X,Y)=\hom_C(FX,Y)$ is the set of morphisms $FX\to Y$ in $C$ (and similarly $\operatorname{hom}_D(\_,G\_)(X,Y)=\hom_D(X,GY)$ is the set of morphisms $X\to GY$ in $D$).

Note that your suggestion wouldn't make sense in general : if $C\neq D$, then there is no such thing as a morphism $FX\to X$, since $X$ must be an object in $D$ and $FX$ an object in $C$.

Answer (score 0):

Each dash is an independent variable, so that $Hom_C(F-,-)$ can accept the input $(X,Y)$ to obtain $Hom_C(FX,Y)$.  I'll leave it to you to work out the variances.